# Jquery hide/show templates

Tags: jquery, css

I have two css templates i.e wrapper1 and wrapper2 and both are 300 x 250. I want to show template 1 then hide the template 1 and show the template 2. This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ27x/) and i am doing using jquery.

```
<div id="wrapper1">
    Template1
</div>

<div id="wrapper2">
    Template2
</div> 

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper1").delay( 800 ).fadeOut( 400 );
    $("#wrapper2").delay( 1000 ).show();
});
```

what i am doing wrong here??.

Comment: *"What i am doing wrong here?"* - Its hard to say. What's happening, and how is it different than what you expect?

Comment: its not working like i the start it is showing both templates but i need template 2 to be hidden and then show the template1 then hide it and template 2 are you getting me?

Comment: OK, so what does *"...its not working..."* mean? How is it not working? Does the page not load? Does the page lock up the browser? Is wrapper1 never shown? Is wrapper1 never faded? Or is wrapper2 never shown? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At init hide `#wrapper2`. After 800 ms `fadeOut` `#wrapper1` and show `#wrapper2` as callback.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#wrapper2").hide();

$("#wrapper1").delay( 800 ).fadeOut( 400 , function() {

    $("#wrapper2").delay( 200 ).show();

});

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/7B7eF/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrapper1").delay(800).fadeOut(400, function () {
        $("#wrapper2").delay(400).show();
    });
});
```

Also, add:

```
display:none;
```

To `#wrapper1`.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/wujevedo/1/edit)**